# Case 3: if n is multiple of both 3 and 5

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm not able to find the write line for third case. I'm a beginner in programming world. Much appreciated if someone helped me with this Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    if(n%3==0) {
      printf("\n 1");}
    else if(n%5==0){
      printf("\n 2");}
    else if((n%3==0) && (n%5==0)){
      printf("\n 3");}
    else{
      printf("\n 4");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should put `if((n%3==0) && (n%5==0))` first.

Comment: Suppose `n` is 15. Go over the code line by line and try to figure out how it will behave and why.

Comment: If you want to test both cases, then do not use `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3. test condition, `else if ((n % 3 == 0) && (n % 5 == 0))`, will never be true, because if `n % 3 == 0` the 1. test, `if (n % 3 == 0)`, will catch it before. The same goes for the case if `n % 5 == 0` with the 2. test, `else if (n % 5 == 0)`.

You need to place `if ((n % 3 == 0) && (n % 5 == 0))` at the start instead to proof both sub-expressions before the testing for each sub-expression:

```
scanf("%d",&n);

if ((n % 3 == 0) && (n % 5 == 0)) {
  printf("\n 1");
}
else if (n % 5 == 0) {
  printf("\n 2");
}
else if (n % 3 == 0) {
  printf("\n 3");
}
else {
  printf("\n 4");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you check if the number can be divided by 3, then you check if it can be divided by 5 and then if it can be divided by both.

If it can be divided by both (in other words it can be divided by 15), then it can be divided by 3, so you'll get out of the first loop and print "\n 1".

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of your test. If you put the longest case first, then if both n%3 and n%5 == 0, it will print. Otherwise, it can be one or the other.

```
if (n%3 == 0 && n%5 == 0)
{ 
   printf("\n 3"); // You might want this to be printf("3\n"); instead
}
else if... // other cases.
```

Another way to do it if you really want to keep the order is to test on the single cases that they aren't both true, ie:

```
if (n%3 == 0 && n%5 != 0)
{
   // Only a multiple of 3
}
else if (n%5 == 0 && n%3 != 0)
{
   // Only a multiple of 5
}
else if (n%3 == 0 && n%5 == 0)
{
  // Multiple of 3 and 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not able to find the write line for third case.

```
else if((n%3==0) && (n%5==0))
```

3rd line never true as first `if(n%3==0)`  would have also been true and code would have executed that block.

---

Simplify with

```
//         v------v                 1 for multiple of 3              
//                        v------v  2 for multiple of 5
int m15 = (n%3 == 0)*1 + (n%5 == 0)*2;
if (m15 == 0) m15 = 4;
printf("\n %d", m15);`
```